# Scrolling grid background with QML

Tags: qt, background, qml

I am trying to make a kind of game with a background that scroll to infinity.
To make it work, I used a Rectangle and a layer. The layer is used for the color of the background. The layer is used to draw line on top of the rectangle.
I add a kind of offset to change the position of the background, but without any effect...

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: root;
    property color colorBackground: Qt.rgba(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
    property color colorStroke: Qt.rgba(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
    property real mapPosition: 0.0;
    layer.enabled: true;

    layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
        property color colorStroke: root.colorStroke;
        property real widthRectangle: rectangle.width;
        property real heightRectangle: rectangle.height;
        property real cellSize: rectangle.width / 5;
        property real mapPosition: root.mapPosition;

        fragmentShader: "
            uniform lowp sampler2D source; // this item
            uniform highp vec4 colorStroke;
            uniform highp float widthRectangle;
            uniform highp float heightRectangle;
            uniform highp float cellSize;
            uniform highp float mapPosition;
            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
            void main() {
                lowp vec4 p = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0);
                gl_FragColor = p;

                float x = qt_TexCoord0.x * widthRectangle;
                float y = qt_TexCoord0.y * heightRectangle + mapPosition;

                if(mod(x, cellSize) <= 1.0)
                    gl_FragColor = colorStroke;

                if(mod(y, cellSize) <= 1.0)
                    gl_FragColor = colorStroke;
            }";
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle;
        color: root.colorBackground;
        anchors.fill: parent;
    }
}
```

To change the position I am using that :

```
import "GameLogic.js" as GameLogic
Background {
    anchors.fill: parent;
    mapPosition: GameLogic.mapPosition;
}
```

But it seems that the background does not move at all...
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use 2 rectangles, one behind another one?

Comment: It is an idea. I will search how To do it